# Find all the childern and subschildern of a node who have same name in n array tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I need to find all the childern and subchildern of a node in an n array tree excluding the parent whose name match a certain string. For example the hierarchy is:

```
root
  - x(a1)
    -a
    -b
    -x(a2)
  -x(a3)
  -x(a4)
```

now when I call root.find("x") it should return a1,a2,a3,a4
when I call a1.find("x") it should return only the childern matching and not the parent i.e return only a2.

I wrote something but that looks kinda hacky. Here is what I wrote. Was thinking how I can optimize it and write some clean code

```
class Node {
    
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Node> nodes;
    private Node parent;

    Node(String name, Node parent) {
        this.name = name;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    }

    public Node parent() {
        return this.parent;
    }

    public String name() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public ArrayList<Node> nodes() {
        return this.nodes;
    }

    public Node addChild(String name) {
        Node child = new Node(name, this);
        this.nodes.add(child);
        return child;
    }


    public ArrayList<Node> find(String query) {
        ArrayList<Node> result = new ArrayList<Node>();
        find(query,result,false);
        return result;
    }

    public void find(String query,ArrayList<Node> result,boolean isIncluded) {
        if ( name().equalsIgnoreCase( query ) && isIncluded) {
            result.add(this);
        }
        //ArrayList<Node> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Node child : this.nodes) {
            child.find(query,result,true);
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Options

1. current code with minor change to access modifier for the second `find` method  - can be changed to `private` or `protected` to avoid other using this in their code (otherwise have to maintain this logic forever)
2. Iterate over all the children in the primary method and invoke the another `find` method that will add any matched entry to result

### Second Option Implementation

Assumes `nodes` will be non-null

```java
    public List<Node> find(final String query) {
        final List<Node> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final Node child : nodes) {
           // if multithreading is required, 
           // then make a `Callable` and invoke find for each child in thread pool
           // and add the reference to the `Future` to a list
           // and add separate loop to get results from the `Future`
           final List<Node> partial = child.find(query, new ArrayList<>());
           result.addAll(partial);
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected List<Node> find(final String query, final List<Node> result) {
        if (name().equalsIgnoreCase(query)) {
            result.add(this);
        }

        for (final Node child : nodes) {
            child.find(query, result);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Raised some valid points. Any reason that you are using final in lot of places

Comment: @rajatnagpal, it helps any future maintainer of the code that you intent to not modify those values. It reduces the complexity in understanding large code bases. Further, in multithreaded environments, using final adds confidence on variable states during debugging (without the need to add volatile)